# How do I backup only my own modifications to a git repository?

Tags: git

If I download some repo off the internet, let's call it "somerepo", then create a "mods" branch and make several commits to that branch, how can I backup only my mods, so that later I can redownload the repository, and reapply my modifications to the commit tree?

Comment: If you're talking about something from GitHub, you could "fork" it. Otherwise, create a new repo somewhere and push. But if the repo you have modified changes, you will be unable to apply your changes without merging.

Comment: Note that your downloaded repo is a full-fledged repo in its own right; if you clone the repo again elsewhere, you can use the former as an origin to pull from.

Comment: So backup only your branch? And possibly without the older history?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, is that possible? The goal is later to reapply it when the source is re-downloaded, such that it branches from the same commit, or if necessary, from HEAD but with the option to fix any inconsistencies. The main concern is to avoid bloat on backup when I want to change a single line in a repo that weighs 6 big ones

Comment: Although I don't really see the difference, given the the original repo is on github for anyone to download. Just keeping two local copies is a bit of a burden just to save my own changes. Anyways, I think there's no "official" support for it, but anyone can achieve that effect with a script. Was just wondering if there is an explicit tool/method to do it, guess not.

Comment: I never used your use case, but I think `git format-patch` and `git am` can do the job (just ignore the part about sending emails). It is a method to share changes without sharing a git repository.